# Problems installing AucTeX over Emacs 24 (OSX)

Tags: emacs, auctex

http://pastebin.com/fbzXTdCU

Above is a terminal log for those who would make sense of it, but basically I have done the following things in order to get the lovely promises of Emacs' [screenshots](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/images/latex.png):

1. Downloaded AucTeX through [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/how-to-preview-latex-in-emacs), which includes the package in question `preview-latex`
2. Read `README` and `INSTALL`, ran `./configure` as advised.
3. Realized Xcode's awful [habits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion) and made `make` a thing in my actual path
4. Ran `./configure` again, 'successfully' - followed by `make` and `make install`
5. Fired up Emacs, noticed the lack of menu (supposed to be tell-tale of a successful install) and then fired up proper `emacs`, to no effect.
6. Ran ./configure again, but specifying which emacs to work with (`Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`), and it gave an error about not being able to find my `texmf` folder, so I ran it again with that (and the lisp directory, it couldn't find that either)
7. Did some more research. Turned out I gave it the wrong lispdir at first (`lisp` instead of `site-lisp`). Tried the same call again with the modified option.

The most recent call I ended up making was [line 2490](http://pastebin.com/fbzXTdCU) in the log above:

```
./configure --with-texmf-dir=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf                 --with-emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs                 --with-lispdir=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/site-lisp
```

Nothing has worked. Can anybody tell me what piece of this puzzle I'm missing? I'm running OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: I should note that the most reliable way to install packages now is through `list-packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have everything mostly working now. I neglected to actually *load* the packages in my `.emacs` file. I still can't get `preview-latex` to work right (keeps bombing out), but I'm going to keep researching that issue. I've also modified my default pdf viewer. Below is the relevant portion of my `.emacs` file:

```
 ;; Adds stuff to my PATH (LaTeX, etc) 
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))

 ;; Set the default LaTeX exec to pdfTeX
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

 ;; Load AucTeX!! :D
(load "auctex.el" nil t t) ;; loads tex-site in such a way so that it can be undone
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t) ;; actual preview-latex

 ;; Sets the default PDF viewer to, well, the default PDF viewer.
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Shell Default" "open %o")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Shell Default")))
```

Then, I figured out that GhostScript was in fact *not* installed on my machine (as MacTeX 2012 should have done), so I just installed it. Now it's saying 'no preview images'. Working on that.

Comment: It's a sad day when your research to try to fix this problem brings you back to this same question.