# Latex Error/Warning Messages in other languages

Tags: languages, accessibility

This is connected to another question ([LaTeX and disability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398304/latex-and-disability)). I would like to use LaTeX for helping a very intelligent boy with severe disability. One problem is that he does not speak a good English. Is there any TeX/LaTeX extension/modification which translates the runtime error and warning messages in other languages (Italian, say)?

Comment: I don't think that would be really useful. He couldn't search on the internet for such messages if he needs help and a lot documentation exists only in english. He should better translate the messages online to get a rough idea about the meaning and improve his english.

Comment: You can also send this question to the [GUIT forum](https://www.guitex.org/home/forum/index?lang=it) (Italian TeX Users Group). He would find also some help there.